# PHP - Switch var value Auto increment working unexpectedly inside a While

Tags: php, html, while-loop, switch-statement

hope you can help me with this one... So basically, I'm testing a switch inside a While, that loops and compares values (once a certain value reaches the limit $numRow, the while ends and stops executing rest of code).

My code below:

```
    <?php

$n = 0;
$i = 0;
$numRows = 4;

while ($n <= $numRows){
    switch($i++){
        case 1:
            if($i == $numRows){
                echo 'Case 1:La variable i ='.$i.' es igual a la cantidad de columnas n='.$n."<br/>"; 
                
            } else {
                echo 'Case 1: La variable i ='.$i.' es diferente a la cantidad de columnas n='.$n."<br/>";   
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if($i == $numRows){
                echo 'Case 2:La variable i ='.$i.' es igual a la cantidad de columnas n='.$n."<br/>";   
            } else {
                echo 'Case 2:La variable i ='.$i.' es diferente a la cantidad de columnas n='.$n."<br/>";   
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            if($i == $numRows){
                echo 'Case 3:La variable i ='.$i.' es igual a la cantidad de columnas n='.$n."<br/>";   
            } else {
                echo 'Case 3:La variable i ='.$i.' es diferente a la cantidad de columnas n='.$n."<br/>";   
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            if($i == $numRows){
                echo 'Case4:La variable i ='.$i.' es igual a la cantidad de columnas n='.$n."<br/>";   
            } else {
                echo 'Case 4:La variable i ='.$i.' es diferente a la cantidad de columnas n='.$n."<br/>";   
            }
            break;
        case 5:
            if($i == $numRows){
                echo 'Case 5:La variable i ='.$i.' es igual a la cantidad de columnas n='.$n."<br/>";   
            } else {
                echo 'Case 5: La variable i ='.$i.' es diferente a la cantidad de columnas n='.$n."<br/>";   
            }
            break;
    }
    $n++;
    echo $n;
}
```

What seems weird to me is the output of the code. Variable $I should start at 1, but instead in case 1 it takes the value of 2... is that even possible? There's no other operation in the code which sums +1 to the variable...

Output:

```
1Case 1: La variable i =2 es diferente a la cantidad de columnas n=1
2Case 2:La variable i =3 es diferente a la cantidad de columnas n=2
3Case 3:La variable i =4 es igual a la cantidad de columnas n=3
4Case 4:La variable i =5 es diferente a la cantidad de columnas n=4
5
```

Is there any typo or something I'm doing wrong with the syntax? I'm learning PHP as a hobby, so would like to understand if there's any novice mistake here :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `switch($i++){` change to `switch($i){`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use pre-incrementation: `++$i` instead of `$i++`:

```
switch(++$i){
//...
}
```

What is happening is when you post-increment (`$i++`), the variable does not take the new value immediately. It takes the new value only when you use the variable again. So when you increment in the switch `$i` is still `1`. Then in the `case: 1`, when you use the variable the actual incrementation happens and it shows 2 instead of 1.

This will be exactly the same as doing:

```
$++;
switch($i){
//...
}
```

Read more about it [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php).

Answer (score -1):

If you want to increment $i each loop, better to

```
$i++
switch($i){
```